# PDFBox to byte array length 0

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pdfbox

Im trying to create an PDF with PDFBox and attach it to an eMail.

Code of the pdf creation (the pdf is succesfully created):

```
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);

     // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

    // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

    // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
    contentStream.drawString("Hello World");
    contentStream.endText();

    // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
    contentStream.close();

    // Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
    document.save("D:\\test.pdf");
    document.close();
    PDStream contents = new PDStream(document);
    byte[] byteArray = contents.getByteArray();
    return byteArray;
```

The `byteArrays`length is size 0 after using `contents.getByteArray();`, but why?

[image: image of the debug values]

Comment: not a java expert (nor have I ever used pdfbox specifically), but I'm betting it's because you closed your stream after saving it (which is correct).  If PDFStream has an overload to read from a file path, you might try that instead...

Comment: Also, unless you have a specific need to actually store the copy of the PDF locally, i'd avoid it.  Writing to disk is a rather slow (comparatively) operation compared to storing it in memory.  This could very well cause you issues further down the line if there's a lot of users in the system at the same time.

Comment: I tried to close the stream atfer I get the byte array as @Jordi Castilla suggested. It doesn´t chance the problem.
The save of the PDF to the local disc was just a test to see if the PDF gets created or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
document.save("D:\\test.pdf");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
document.save(baos);
document.close();
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I just tried this at the same minute. This works fine! But I still don´t know why the PDStream is empty.

Comment: Because that is the purpose... it creates a new (empty) stream connected to the document.

Comment: The "PDStream" isn't the pdf, it is used for parts of a pdf, e.g. an image, or a content stream, a colorspace component, ...